# In Django settings TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

> File "D:\Python Development\Django_Broad\blog\blog\settings.py", line 19, in 
> ALLOWED_HOSTS =config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=csv())
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Why am I getting this error? someone help me..

Comment: The short answer to your question is that you get this error because you are trying to call a module like it is a function, but this isn't alllowed. However, I'm not able to help you find the right way to do what you want without some more details. What are you trying to do with `ALLOWED_HOSTS =config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=csv())`?

Comment: What is `config` and what is `csv`?

Comment: actually, i am trying to host the Django project,, config and cvs are python packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv as a module is not callable which means you cannot do `csv()`, I don't know how `config` works, but why do you not just use ALLOWED_HOSTS as from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)?

locally you can just do:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```

After some research I found this code, which looks quite similar to yours and seems to resolve the problem that you have not right capitalization of `Csv`:

```
from decouple import config, Csv

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())
```